# How do I speed up transistor switching in low side power switch?

Tags: transistors, motor, switches, circuit-design, frequency

I am working on a project and want to drive a motor with a 12V PWM signal (Motor connected to 12V and the Motor- net on the diagram).

The circuit below is an idea I have, however after I built it, it turns out it has quite a slow turn on and turn of time. What are some methods of speeding that up?

Thanks in advance,

Rob

[image: Motor Drive Circuit]

---

**Edit 1: Adding scope plots of input and output as requested.**

*Plot 1 - Between R31 and U4*

[image: Input Plot]

*Plot 2 - Probe at "Motor-"*

[image]

**Edit 2: Adding schematic of circuit to the right (Current sensing).**

[image: Current Sense]

Comment: Slow in what respect? Delay time? Rise or fall time? What does you input signal look like? Does it have any delays associated with it?

Comment: Hi Andy aka, thanks for the comment. I will edit the question and add scope plots of the input and output currently.

Comment: What is R9 used for? Where does the connection go to the right? If it's used in a current limiter circuit this could explain why the motor voltage slope is present.

Comment: It is a current sensing circuit.

Comment: And does that current sensing circuit have a controlling influence on the motor drive circuit?

Comment: No, not at the moment. I have simply set the duty cycle to 50%.

Comment: Is the power rail remaining stable throughout or does it show signs of collapsing cyclically?

Comment: 12V and 3.3V power rails are stable

Answer (score 1):

The slowly ramping voltage is what I suspect will happen when the MOSFET is turned off - when you deactivate the MOSFET the motor momentarily turns into a generator. Normally, with an inductive load you will get a back-emf that forward biases the protection diode but you also have a snubber that can do the same thing but somewhere between the snubber and the motor acting as a generator when the MOSFET turns off I suspect you get this effect.

I suggest you try and model the situation.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem @RobertGilmore

Answer (score 0):

While you do not make clear what the voltage of the PWM is, The voltage on R21 should be half the supply voltage. this will remove the influence of any capacitance at the inputs from slowing down the transition,

Next up, would be loose R32, the whole point of U4 is to slam that mosfet on and off as fast as possible, that resistor is preventing it, with a normal op amp it would be recommended, but this device is intended to deal with capacitive loads.

Comment: Thanks ReRoute for you input. The PWM switches between 12V and GND. I had thought about your second point, and I will try that. Do you have any tips for choosing an optimum resistance for R32?

Comment: Your first point about R21, I am not sure how I can improved that. A micro-controller is driving the "MotorPWM" net. and that will be with a 3.3V signal. I don't have the option to make it 6V as you say (12V/2)?

Comment: none at all for this use case, a hard short, the gate driver wants to switch +-2.5A through the mosfet gate, in order to switch it as fast as possible

Comment: Do you have any advice on switch off characteristics. Or is that similar? Could I tune the C12 and R12 circuit? If i'm not wrong, that is called a snubber? 

Thanks again

Comment: R21, feed from say 2x 10K resistors dividing the 3.3V rail in half, then feed that ~1.65V to the + input

Comment: Ah gotcha! Thanks

Comment: C12/R12 are mainly there to make up for how slow the diodes might be, I would need to know the size of the motor to get a feel for if they are suitable

Answer (score 0):

At first, before I get to the main point: According to the data sheet, the FAN3100 is not a comparator. The inputs are logic inputs. So, the 3.3V at R21 to the IN+-Pin seems to be all right and should not effect the switching speed.

My suspicion is, that the switching time is slow, because the gate charge does not get reloaded fast enough because the current is to low.

The driver applies 12V to the gate with a driving capability of up to 3A. The 22Ohm resistor R32 limits this to about 0.5A. Imagine the gate as a capacitor, that must be charged from 0V (off state) to 12V (on state). R32 and the gate capacitance (3247pF according to the data sheet) form a shunted capacitor. You can calculate the pulse response with the usual formulas.

As a result, I would change R32 to 4.7Ohms (resulting in 2.55A driven into the gate) and increase the bulk capacitor C10 to a value of 10µF to 47µF. The current pulse to reload the gate, comes almost entirely from this capacitor. It must provide the 2.5A that are driven into the gate. A ceramic capacitor does not work as C10, it must be a bulk polarized electrolytic or tantalum capacitor. Chose the lowest ESR you can get or place two capacitors in parallel instead of only one C10. Having to much capacitance at this point does not do any harm. The capacitors should be placed as close to the driver IC as possible.

Be also aware that ceramic capacitors show a DC-bias effect. So C1 on your circuit must be chosen accordingly. Many types of ceramic capacitors have only 10% of the original capacitance at voltages of 12V and above which makes them practically inoperative.

Some additional point to think about: Do you really need such a big fat FET? Its capacitance is quit high, which slows down the switching time. Its rise and fall times are also rather slow. So, choosing a 'smaller' FET with less driving capability and therefore less gate capacitance and faster rise and fall times, should also help to increase the switching speed. I cannot imagine, that you really need 110A in your application.

Rather lengthy answer, I apologize, but I hope it will help. Good luck and all the best!

Comment: Hi Lexi, this is a great answer. Thank you, I will take these comments on board and likely implement some of them.

Comment: Hi Robert! Thanks for the nice comment. I am working on a project with similar problems. It would be nice to hear who you manged to get the turn and off times of the FET shorter.